# Using Gulp and Babel to compile ES2015 going ridiculously slow

Tags: gulp, babeljs

I'm trying to move to a modern build system like Gulp, so I can use fancy things like ES2015 and JSX, but I just can't get it to work. This started out way more complicated, and I've cut it down to the simplest it can be, and it doesn't run fast enough.

Here is the layout

```
 - folder
   - src
     - main.js
   - node_modules
     ...
   - gulpfile.js
   - .babelrc
```

The gulpfile is as simple as I could get it.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/main.js')
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

The babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"],
}
```

And finally, just to make sure this isn't the bottleneck, this is what I'm trying to transpile:

```
const x = 0;
```

The result of running `gulp` from that directory?

[image: this is how slow it gets]

Two and a half minutes. It works. In /dist I get a file called 'main.js' which contains

```
"use strict";

var x = 0;
```

but there's not way it's supposed to be that slow.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

---

Result of `npm ls`

```
├── amdefine@1.0.0
├── ansi-green@0.1.1
├── ansi-regex@2.0.0
├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
├── ansi-wrap@0.1.0
├── anymatch@1.3.0
├── arr-diff@2.0.0
├── arr-flatten@1.0.1
├── array-uniq@1.0.2
├── array-unique@0.2.1
├── arrify@1.0.1
├── asn1@0.2.3
├── assert-plus@0.1.5
├── async@1.5.1
├── async-each@0.1.6
├── aws-sign2@0.6.0
├── babel-cli@6.3.17
├── babel-code-frame@6.3.13
├── babel-core@6.3.26
├── babel-generator@6.3.26
├── babel-helpers@6.3.13
├── babel-messages@6.3.18
├── babel-polyfill@6.3.14
├─┬ babel-preset-es2015@6.3.13
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants@6.3.13
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions@6.3.13
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions@6.3.13
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping@6.3.13
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │ │ └── core-js@1.2.6
│ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.3.13
│ │ │ └── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │ │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │ │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │ │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │ │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │ └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ │ └── lodash@3.10.1
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes@6.3.15
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-define-map@6.3.13
│ │ │ └── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-function-name@6.3.15
│ │ │ └── babel-helper-get-function-arity@6.3.13
│ │ ├── babel-helper-optimise-call-expression@6.3.13
│ │ ├── babel-helper-replace-supers@6.3.13
│ │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │ │ └── core-js@1.2.6
│ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.3.13
│ │ │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ └── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │ │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │ │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │ │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │ │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│ │   ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │   ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │   └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties@6.3.13
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-define-map@6.3.13
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-function-name@6.3.15
│ │ │ │ ├── babel-helper-get-function-arity@6.3.13
│ │ │ │ └─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │ │ │   ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │ │ │   │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ │ │   │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │ │ │   │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │ │ │   │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ │   │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │   │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │ │ │   │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │   │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ │ │   │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │ │   │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │   │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │ │ │   │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │ │ │   ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │ │ │   ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ │   ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ │ │   │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │ │ │   ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │ │ │   ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │ │ │   │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │ │ │   │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │   └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │ │     └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │ │       └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │ │ │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │ │ │ │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │ │ │ │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │ │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │ │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │ │ └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ │ │ └── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │ │ └── core-js@1.2.6
│ │ └─┬ babel-template@6.3.13
│ │   ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │   │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │   │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │   │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │   │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │   │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │   │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │   │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │   │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │   │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │   │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │   │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │   │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │   │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │   │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │   │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │   │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │   │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │   ├─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│ │   │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │   │ └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ │   ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │   └── lodash@3.10.1
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring@6.3.15
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of@6.3.13
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name@6.3.21
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-function-name@6.3.15
│ │ │ ├── babel-helper-get-function-arity@6.3.13
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.3.13
│ │ │ │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ │ └── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ │ └─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │ │   ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │ │   │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ │   │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │ │   │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │ │   │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │   │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │   │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │ │   │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │   │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ │   │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │   │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │   │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │ │   │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │ │   ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │ │   ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │   ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ │   │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │ │   ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │ │   ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │ │   │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │ │   │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │   ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ │   └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │     └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │       └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │ │ └── core-js@1.2.6
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│ │   ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │   │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │   │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │   │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │   │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │   │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │   │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │   │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │   │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │   │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │   │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │   │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │   │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │   │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │   │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │   │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │   │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │   │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │   ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │   ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │   └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals@6.3.13
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs@6.3.16
│ │ ├── babel-plugin-transform-strict-mode@6.3.13
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │ │ └── core-js@1.2.6
│ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.3.13
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │ │ │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │ │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │ │ │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ └── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│ │   ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │   │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │   │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │   │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │   │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │   │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │   │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │   │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │   │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │   │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │   │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │   │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │   │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │   │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │   │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │   │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │   │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │   │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │   ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │   ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │   └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-object-super@6.3.13
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-replace-supers@6.3.13
│ │ │ ├── babel-helper-optimise-call-expression@6.3.13
│ │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.3.13
│ │ │ │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ │ └── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │ │ │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │ │ │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │ │ │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ │ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│ │ │   ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │   ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ │   └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-parameters@6.3.26
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-call-delegate@6.3.13
│ │ │ └── babel-helper-hoist-variables@6.3.13
│ │ ├── babel-helper-get-function-arity@6.3.13
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │ │ └── core-js@1.2.6
│ │ ├─┬ babel-template@6.3.13
│ │ │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ └── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │ │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │ │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │ │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │ │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│ │   ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │   ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │   └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties@6.3.13
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │ │ └── core-js@1.2.6
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│ │   ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │   │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │   │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │   │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │   │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │   │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │   │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │   │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │   │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │   │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │   │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │   │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │   │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │   │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │   │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │   │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │   │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │   │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │   ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │   ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │   └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread@6.3.14
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex@6.3.13
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-regex@6.3.13
│ │ │ └── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │ │ └── core-js@1.2.6
│ │ └─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│ │   ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │   │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │   │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │   │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │   │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │   │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │   │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │   │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │   │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │   │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │   │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │   │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │   │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │   │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │   │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │   │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │   │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │   │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │   ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │   ├── lodash@3.10.1
│ │   └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals@6.3.13
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol@6.3.13
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-es2015-unicode-regex@6.3.13
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-regex@6.3.13
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │ │ │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │ │ │ │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │ │ │ │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │ │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │ │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │ │ └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ │ │ └── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ ├─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │ │ └── core-js@1.2.6
│ │ └─┬ regexpu@1.3.0
│ │   ├── esprima@2.7.1
│ │   ├─┬ recast@0.10.39
│ │   │ ├── ast-types@0.8.12
│ │   │ ├── esprima-fb@15001.1001.0-dev-harmony-fb
│ │   │ ├── private@0.1.6
│ │   │ └── source-map@0.5.3
│ │   ├── regenerate@1.2.1
│ │   ├── regjsgen@0.2.0
│ │   └─┬ regjsparser@0.1.5
│ │     └── jsesc@0.5.0
│ └─┬ babel-plugin-transform-regenerator@6.3.26
│   ├─┬ babel-core@6.3.26
│   │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│   │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│   │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│   │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│   │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│   │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│   │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│   │ │ ├─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│   │ │ │ └── left-pad@0.0.3
│   │ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│   │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│   │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│   │ ├─┬ babel-generator@6.3.26
│   │ │ ├─┬ detect-indent@3.0.1
│   │ │ │ ├── get-stdin@4.0.1
│   │ │ │ └── minimist@1.2.0
│   │ │ ├─┬ is-integer@1.0.6
│   │ │ │ └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│   │ │ │   └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│   │ │ ├─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│   │ │ │ └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│   │ │ │   └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│   │ │ └── trim-right@1.0.1
│   │ ├── babel-helpers@6.3.13
│   │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│   │ ├─┬ babel-register@6.3.13
│   │ │ ├── core-js@1.2.6
│   │ │ ├─┬ home-or-tmp@1.0.0
│   │ │ │ ├── os-tmpdir@1.0.1
│   │ │ │ └── user-home@1.1.1
│   │ │ └─┬ source-map-support@0.2.10
│   │ │   └─┬ source-map@0.1.32
│   │ │     └── amdefine@1.0.0
│   │ ├── babel-template@6.3.13
│   │ ├── convert-source-map@1.1.3
│   │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│   │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│   │ ├── json5@0.4.0
│   │ ├── lodash@3.10.1
│   │ ├─┬ minimatch@2.0.10
│   │ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.2
│   │ │   ├── balanced-match@0.3.0
│   │ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1
│   │ ├── path-exists@1.0.0
│   │ ├── path-is-absolute@1.0.0
│   │ ├── shebang-regex@1.0.0
│   │ ├── slash@1.0.0
│   │ └── source-map@0.5.3
│   ├── babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions@6.3.13
│   ├─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│   │ └── core-js@1.2.6
│   ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│   │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│   │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│   │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│   │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│   │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│   │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│   │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│   │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│   │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│   │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│   │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│   │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│   │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│   │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│   │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│   │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│   │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│   │ ├── lodash@3.10.1
│   │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│   │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│   │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│   ├─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│   │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│   │ ├── lodash@3.10.1
│   │ └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│   ├── babylon@6.3.26
│   └── private@0.1.6
├─┬ babel-preset-react@6.3.13
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-syntax-flow@6.3.13
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-syntax-jsx@6.3.13
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@6.3.15
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-react-display-name@6.3.13
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ ├─┬ babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx@6.3.13
│ │ ├─┬ babel-helper-builder-react-jsx@6.3.13
│ │ │ ├─┬ babel-types@6.3.24
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-traverse@6.3.26
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.3.13
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ ├── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ line-numbers@0.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ │   └── left-pad@0.0.3
│ │ │ │ │ ├── babel-messages@6.3.18
│ │ │ │ │ ├── babylon@6.3.26
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ │ │ │ │ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ invariant@2.2.0
│ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ loose-envify@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ │   └── js-tokens@1.0.2
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ repeating@1.1.3
│ │ │ │ │   └─┬ is-finite@1.0.1
│ │ │ │ │     └── number-is-nan@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ └── to-fast-properties@1.0.1
│ │ │ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ │ │ └── lodash@3.10.1
│ │ └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│ │   └── core-js@1.2.6
│ └─┬ babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source@6.3.13
│   └─┬ babel-runtime@5.8.34
│     └── core-js@1.2.6
├── babel-regenerator-runtime@6.3.13
├── babel-register@6.3.13
├── babel-runtime@5.8.34
├── babel-template@6.3.13
├── babel-traverse@6.3.26
├── babel-types@6.3.24
├── babylon@6.3.26
├── balanced-match@0.3.0
├── bin-version@1.0.4
├── bin-version-check@2.1.0
├── binary-extensions@1.4.0
├── bl@1.0.0
├── boom@2.10.1
├── brace-expansion@1.1.2
├── braces@1.8.3
├── builtin-modules@1.1.1
├── camelcase@2.0.1
├── camelcase-keys@2.0.0
├── caseless@0.11.0
├── chalk@1.1.1
├── chokidar@1.4.2
├── combined-stream@1.0.5
├── commander@2.9.0
├── concat-map@0.0.1
├── convert-source-map@1.1.3
├── core-js@1.2.6
├── core-util-is@1.0.2
├── cryptiles@2.0.5
├── dashdash@1.11.0
├── debug@2.2.0
├── decamelize@1.1.2
├── delayed-stream@1.0.0
├── detect-indent@3.0.1
├── ecc-jsbn@0.1.1
├── error-ex@1.3.0
├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
├─┬ eslint@1.10.3
│ ├─┬ chalk@1.1.1
│ │ ├── ansi-styles@2.1.0
│ │ ├─┬ has-ansi@2.0.0
│ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ strip-ansi@3.0.0
│ │ │ └── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ └── supports-color@2.0.0
│ ├─┬ concat-stream@1.5.1
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ ├─┬ readable-stream@2.0.5
│ │ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
│ │ │ ├── isarray@0.0.1
│ │ │ ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.6
│ │ │ ├── string_decoder@0.10.31
│ │ │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2
│ │ └── typedarray@0.0.6
│ ├─┬ debug@2.2.0
│ │ └── ms@0.7.1
│ ├─┬ doctrine@0.7.2
│ │ ├── esutils@1.1.6
│ │ └── isarray@0.0.1
│ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4
│ ├─┬ escope@3.3.0
│ │ ├─┬ es6-map@0.1.3
│ │ │ ├── d@0.1.1
│ │ │ ├── es5-ext@0.10.11
│ │ │ ├── es6-iterator@2.0.0
│ │ │ ├── es6-set@0.1.3
│ │ │ ├── es6-symbol@3.0.2
│ │ │ └── event-emitter@0.3.4
│ │ ├─┬ es6-weak-map@2.0.1
│ │ │ ├── d@0.1.1
│ │ │ ├── es5-ext@0.10.11
│ │ │ ├── es6-iterator@2.0.0
│ │ │ └── es6-symbol@3.0.2
│ │ └─┬ esrecurse@3.1.1
│ │   └── estraverse@3.1.0
│ ├── espree@2.2.5
│ ├── estraverse@4.1.1
│ ├── estraverse-fb@1.3.1
│ ├── esutils@2.0.2
│ ├─┬ file-entry-cache@1.2.4
│ │ └─┬ flat-cache@1.0.10
│ │   ├─┬ del@2.2.0
│ │   │ ├─┬ globby@4.0.0
│ │   │ │ ├─┬ array-union@1.0.1
│ │   │ │ │ └── array-uniq@1.0.2
│ │   │ │ ├── arrify@1.0.1
│ │   │ │ └─┬ glob@6.0.3
│ │   │ │   ├─┬ inflight@1.0.4
│ │   │ │   │ └── wrappy@1.0.1
│ │   │ │   ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │   │ │   └─┬ once@1.3.3
│ │   │ │     └── wrappy@1.0.1
│ │   │ ├── is-path-cwd@1.0.0
│ │   │ ├─┬ is-path-in-cwd@1.0.0
│ │   │ │ └── is-path-inside@1.0.0
│ │   │ ├── pify@2.3.0
│ │   │ ├─┬ pinkie-promise@2.0.0
│ │   │ │ └── pinkie@2.0.1
│ │   │ └─┬ rimraf@2.5.0
│ │   │   └─┬ glob@6.0.3
│ │   │     ├─┬ inflight@1.0.4
│ │   │     │ └── wrappy@1.0.1
│ │   │     ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │   │     └─┬ once@1.3.3
│ │   │       └── wrappy@1.0.1
│ │   ├── graceful-fs@4.1.2
│ │   ├── read-json-sync@1.1.1
│ │   └── write@0.2.1
│ ├─┬ glob@5.0.15
│ │ ├─┬ inflight@1.0.4
│ │ │ └── wrappy@1.0.1
│ │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
│ │ └─┬ once@1.3.3
│ │   └── wrappy@1.0.1
│ ├── globals@8.17.0
│ ├─┬ handlebars@4.0.5
│ │ ├── async@1.5.1
│ │ ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1
│ │ │ ├── minimist@0.0.10
│ │ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3
│ │ ├─┬ source-map@0.4.4
│ │ │ └── amdefine@1.0.0
│ │ └─┬ uglify-js@2.6.1
│ │   ├── async@0.2.10
│ │   ├── source-map@0.5.3
│ │   ├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2
│ │   └─┬ yargs@3.10.0
│ │     ├── camelcase@1.2.1
│ │     ├─┬ cliui@2.1.0
│ │     │ ├─┬ center-align@0.1.2
│ │     │ │ ├─┬ align-text@0.1.3
│ │     │ │ │ ├─┬ kind-of@2.0.1
│ │     │ │ │ │ └── is-buffer@1.1.1
│ │     │ │ │ ├── longest@1.0.1
│ │     │ │ │ └── repeat-string@1.5.2
│ │     │ │ └── lazy-cache@0.2.7
│ │     │ ├─┬ right-align@0.1.3
│ │     │ │ └─┬ align-text@0.1.3
│ │     │ │   ├─┬ kind-of@2.0.1
│ │     │ │   │ └── is-buffer@1.1.1
│ │     │ │   ├── longest@1.0.1
│ │     │ │   └── repeat-string@1.5.2
│ │     │ └── wordwrap@0.0.2
│ │     ├── decamelize@1.1.2
│ │     └── window-size@0.1.0
│ ├─┬ inquirer@0.11.1
│ │ ├── ansi-escapes@1.1.0
│ │ ├── ansi-regex@2.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ cli-cursor@1.0.2
│ │ │ └─┬ restore-cursor@1.0.1
│ │ │   ├── exit-hook@1.1.1
│ │ │   └── onetime@1.1.0
│ │ ├── cli-width@1.1.0
│ │ ├── figures@1.4.0
│ │ ├── lodash@3.10.1
...
```

Comment: What versions of gulp and gulp-babel are you using? With gulp 3.9.0 and gulp-babel 6.1.1, it runs in 60ms on my side. You can run `npm ls` to see which versions you're using.

Comment: @esteban, I've added that info to the original post. It came up with like 70,000 characters so I had to cut it off. Maybe that's part of the problem?

Comment: Two quick questions to clarify -- is it working properly and just simply slow? And also do you have a `dist` folder already created? (if not try creating the `dist` folder although I doubt this is the actual issue)

Comment: @aug, yes it appears to work. Maybe it wouldn't with something more complicated, but the trivially simple main.js does get compiled. Having `dist` already created doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Did you experiment a lot in this project? You have too many dependencies installed. I'd go with `rm -rf node_modules`, then install your dependencies again. With gulp and gulp-babel it will suffice. Also, to get a shorter (and more interesting) output use `npm ls --depth=0`.

Comment: I ran rm -rf node_modules, and it didn't do anything. It got stuck, not unlike gulp, for several minutes. So I cancelled it and deleted the folder myself, but maybe that's a sign of something?

Comment: Reinstalling just those two, I get this error: `Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory`. I'll add that as well and see what happens.

Comment: You'll want to use npm@3 or at least run `npm dedupe`. Babel can be quite slow if your directories aren't well deduped.

Comment: I ran `npm -v` and found that I'm running 2.14.12. Is that probably the issue? How can I update it - googling lead me to learn that the updater was broken on that version?

Comment: Please read tag descriptions! [tag:babel] is for questions about the Python library with that name! It even explicitly says to use [tag:babeljs] for questions about the JavaScript transpiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for some closure, in case anyone comes across this question: My hard drive had become corrupted. The issue wasn't with Bable or Gulp, it was with my computer.